# Booting Linux minimally

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, root-filesystem

I am trying to boot just linux itself. It's mostly for the learning experience.
I got a small HDD with *only one ext4 partition* looking like this:

```
/bin/bash             
/dev/console
/boot/vmlinuz         
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
/boot/grub/i386-pc/*.mod
```

`bash` is version 3.0 statically linked, `vmlinuz` is version 3.16.2, and `grub` is version 2.00rc1. `grub.cfg` looks like this:

```
insmod linux
insmod search 
insmod ext2
insmod part_msdos
set timeout=5

menuentry 'Linux' {
    set the_root_uuid=a0225737-71c9-4d60-81e2-275dc078c3c1
    search --fs-uuid $the_root_uuid --set=root
    linux /boot/vmlinuz root=$root ro init=/bin/bash
}
```

when booting I get the following:

```
kernel panic: VFS could not open device root (hd0,msdos1), or unknown block(0,0) error -6
```

*What am I missing?*

Comment: Why do you need `part_msdos`?

Comment: @phunehehe i added part_msdos after getting the errormsg, because of the (hd0,msdos1). Didn't change anything though.

Comment: That looks like Linux and Gnu bash, to me.

Comment: I did a search on "VFS error 6" (google does not like the minus sign), and found stuff about missing `initrd` image, and missing drivers for ext4 or disk interface.

Comment: I am trying the same thing and getting a similar error message. See my question here:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151969/booting-into-a-kernel-image  . Also you may find some help in the sources containing this error: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8065be8d032f38da25b54bf077a05a30d9ce9f2a/init/do_mounts.c

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel doesn't include the drivers needed to access the root filesystem (e.g. the ahci sata module and possibly also the ext4 module).

You either need to provide an initrd/initramfs that loads the appropriate modules or you need to compile a kernel that includes the necessary drivers statically (not as modules).

Since your rootfs doesn't include tools to load modules anyway, I suggest you build a non-modular kernel.